# Can I put a radiator on the wall behind a toilet?

Tags: toilet, radiator

I'm thinking of layouts for a bathroom reno, and wall space is at a premium.  There is an existing recessed hot water radiator along one wall and I'd like to place the toilet in front of it.  Because the radiator is in-wall there seems to be enough space behind the toilet for it.  The toilet does not touch the wall.  I don't see any problem with getting the necessary plumbing to both of them.  Is there any problem with this arrangement?

Comment: Wonder if the mass of the toilet plus water would affect heating the room.

Comment: Jay, there is a request from a new user (Lisa) requesting "Just curious if you did this in your Reno. I am thinking of doing the same.can you post photos?" I'm posting the comment as she cannot, her answer will certainly be deleted, and other people may be interested in a follow-up to see how this worked out.

Comment: After demo and removal of the rad I decided not to move it, but to remove it and [install electric floor heat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/248933/65210).  The cost of the floor heat materials was about equal to what the labor would have been to replace the radiator in my new location behind the toilet.   The labor to install the floor heat was trivial, I did most of it myself with free support including video calls from the vendor.  The result is 100 times better in every respect.  In retrospect, this is a silly question. Hard to imagine doing a bathroom and keeping any kind of radiator!

Comment: Further hindsight: I accepted Ecnerwal's answer because after opening the floor and thinking carefully about it, I think implementation and maintenance issues would be a "level of irritation" to say the least.  Also @crisp659 makes a good point above, that I haven't explored fully:  Each winter flush will bring a couple gallons of very cold water that will absorb some of the radiator's heat.  The bathroom might end up a little colder than otherwise because it's not its own zone.   Radiant heat with its own thermostat lets me keep the bathroom a tad warmer than the house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will add a level of irritation to any future repair work, but should not be a show-stopper.

Comment: Good point. I must  make sure the bleed valve is easily accessible, and the control valve also.  Though, the control valve on a recessed radiator is never easily accessible.  If the radiator has to be removed, something that happens maybe once every 70 years, removal of the toilet adds about 1% to the total irritation.